# Web API return valid SOAP message as HttpResponseMessage from rest web service

Tags: web-services, wcf, rest, soap

I have implemented a rest push service. The data pushed to this web service is in a xml format, which i am able to process without any issues. The problem lies in the response, where i need to provide a soap message in the response in this format:

```
<soap:Envelope>
 <soap:Body>
  <Response>OK</Response>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I tried with creating an XmlDocument with this content, then returning it back with the response, but it is either ending up into "unknown" error message or the response is formatted as a string. Can somebody help me further with the implementation? Currently the code is looking like this:

```
        var soapAsString = ConstructSoapResponse("OK");
        var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(soapAsString);

        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, xmlDoc);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/xml; charset=utf-8");
        return response;


    private string ConstructSoapResponse(string message)
    {
        return String.Format(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
            <soap:Body>
                <Response>{0}</Response>
            </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>", message);
    }
```